# How use google places api to display photos of a venue,

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-street-view

```
var str = "";

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.720032,-73.988354&radius=10000&type=bars&keyword=bar&key=KEY-HERE,
  success: function(data){

for(var dt in data.results){
  $('ul').append('<li>'+data.results[dt].name+'</li>');

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='+data.results[dt].place_id+'&key=KEY-HERE',
    success: function(data1){
      for(var i = 0; i < data1.result.reviews.length; i++){
        if(data1.result.reviews){
          str = data1.result.reviews[i].rating;

          $('ul').append('<span>'+str+'</span><li>'+data1.result.reviews[i].author_name+'</li>');
          }
        }

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=40.7484,-73.9857&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=KEY-HERE',
    success: function(data2){
      var attributions = $("#attributions");
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(attributions);
      service.getDetails(data1.results[0].place_id, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            var src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=40.7484,-73.9857&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=KEY-HERE';
             return $("#image").attr('src', sr);
    }
  })
}
```

})

its responding with a 200 status code in my console but not showing the images in my browser, its also giving me one photo for the location yet its supposed to respond with different photos for the venue

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working version of my site at the moment so I can't confirm. I've used other google image API with something like: `<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=40.7484,-73.9857&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=KEY-HERE"/>`

Update: Confirmed above works for

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CmRaAAAATj4PARx8gR50LV2CRGDu5KfKG-MYFcB83wIMLQhnF0B8RyV4tL7uYmfWt3ftSYI5o195Ype4lwpDw3_TS3w5rWihd6qyvOyllc5yyrOUdUVY3jyeEeByQFihmz_kTZ9nEhAOO-m_2By6qwxFK124QJleGhQUjcmjs_8HOQ2RNV5GysJ-Ulg_5Q&key=_____MY_KEY____&maxheight=1000&maxwidth=600" </img>
```